# Is Databinding Textboxes in VB.net with a WHERE clause possible?

Tags: vb.net, data-binding

Is there a way to add databindings including a `WHERE` clause to sort which rows in the table get bound to which text boxes?

```
Serialnametxtbx.DataBinding.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", Me.CoatingKitsBindingSource, "Serial_Number", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, nullValue As Object, formatString As String)
```

I'm not sure what one should use in the `nullValue As Object` location and the `formatString As String` location?

In the below code I have added a `WHERE` statement as to what I would like to sort this by but I am not sure where to implement it.

```
Serialnametxtbx.DataBinding.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", Me.CoatingKitsBindingSource, "Serial_Number WHERE [Description] LIKE '%Banana%'", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, nullValue As Object, formatString As String)
```

Any suggestions? :)

The scenario here is there are 7 items to which need to be assigned as a group to say Kit #1.  Each of these Items have similarities, `Description`, `Unit Number`, `Serial Number`,`Make`,`Model`,`Last Calibration`, `Next Calibration`, `Calibration Company`, `Status` and `Condition`.  For each of the 7 Items there is different information that the user has input into each of these ten text boxes when they have added the piece of equipment.  So I need to bind the piece of equipment's information to individual groups of text boxes on a form for that kit number.

So there are 10 text boxes for each piece of equipment in a kit and there are 7 pieces of equipment in a kit meaning 70 text boxes to the form.  In the table there are the 10 columns for each piece and I would like to bind them as they differentiate by their description.

To select the kit number the user would like to edit I used a binding source filter on a combobox:

```
 Me.Coating_KitsTableAdapter.FillBy(MacroQualityDataSet.Coating_Kits)
    Me.CoatingKitsBindingSource.Filter = ("Unit_Number LIKE '%" & selectcktxtbx.Text & "%'")
```

And populated the list items in it with a dataset which is created when the form loads:

```
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim cs As String = My.Settings.MacroQualityConnectionString
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT DISTINCT Coating_Kits.Unit_Number FROM Coating_Kits"

    Dim connection As New SqlConnection(cs)
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection)

    connection.Open()
    da.Fill(ds, "Coating_Kits")
    connection.Close()

    selectcktxtbx.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    selectcktxtbx.DisplayMember = "Unit_Number"
```

Can I maybe do a databinding off this dataset? I'm totally lost as usual.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Filter` property of the `BindingSource`; the two mystery parameters to the `Binding` constructor are irrelevant (they represent DBNull replacements and display formatting strings respectively). Untested:

```
CoatingKitsBindingSource.Filter = "[Description] LIKE '%Banana%'"
```

Note also that you'll need multiple binding sources if you need different filters, or one control filtered and one not.

Comment: Sorry I should have added more information to the original question, I updated it with more info gathered since this am.

Comment: OK, as I understand it, you'll need 7 binding sources, one for each item in the kit; each will have its own filter that combines the existing unit number filter with whatever other filter part you need, using `AND`, and all of these will need to be updated whenever the unit number combobox changes.

Comment: So I should create a binding source for each item in the kit then bind the boxes individually to each source?  I was trying to filter multiple binding sources the other day and I kept getting an exception cannot filter more than one binding source at a time due to an open data reader from another filter?  Is there a work around for this?

Comment: Hmm. I think using a single separate DataSet for the seven BindingSources might do the job, but I don't know offhand.